# WbExport column names are missing while generating scripts?

Tags: amazon-redshift, export-to-csv, sql-workbench-j

Query:

```
WbExport 
-type=text
-outputDir='D:\Migration'
-delimiter='|'
-quotechar='^'
-encoding=UTF8
-quoteCharEscaping=duplicate
-formatFile=postgres
-header=true
-decimal='.'
-dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'
-sourceTable=database.schema.tablename
```

Oupput sql file:

```
copy tablename()
     from 'D:\Migration'
     with (format csv, header true, quote '^', delimiter '|', encoding 'UTF8', null '');
```

Expected output:

```
copy tablename(column_names)
     from 'D:\Migration'
     with (format csv, header true, quote '^', delimiter '|', encoding 'UTF8', null '');
```

Comment: Yes, it will write out the column names. I can't reproduce the behaviour you are describing. Do you see proper column names when you run `select * from schema.tablename`? Which JDBC driver are you using? Which SQL Workbench build?

Comment: Sql workbench build 117(2015-01-04)

Comment: Jdbc 7.4.1jre8. I tried using same query for small table with rows 1000 and it worked perfectly. But for big tables it is not giving me column names

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ I am getting proper column names when I run select * from schema.tablename

Comment: What is the JDBC driver's version? And does the table name contain an underscore `_`?

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ JDBC driver's version: Jdbc 7.4.1jre8 and table name does contains underscore.

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ when I am writing below query using "select" instead of "-sourcetable" it is working fine but using select I cannot export mutiples/all tables automatically. – vishal waghmode just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58655157/10047216